# Deleting header rule on the first page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, rules

I would like to generate myself a standard, simple report template. In the attached example I would like to have different set of headers on the first page. I'm stuck with a problem trying to remove the *header line* from the first page.

## Code

```
% vim:ft=tex:
%
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

% Use if Arial font unavailable
% \usepackage{helvet}
% \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

% Geometry has to be loaded before the footer
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 bottom=20mm,
 top=20mm
 }

\usepackage{lastpage} % for the last page number
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
% Add a line above footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% default is 0pt
% Add line above footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyfoot[OR]{\footnotesize \thepage\ /\ \pageref{LastPage}}

% Define style to be used for the first page
\fancypagestyle{firststyle}
{
   \fancyhf{}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt} % I would hope for this to delete header rule on the first page
   \fancyfoot[OR]{\footnotesize \thepage\ /\ \pageref{LastPage}}
}

% Title page configuration
\title{\vspace{-2cm}Title of the Document\vspace{-5mm}}
\author{Author\vspace{-5mm}}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

% Use special first page style on the first page
\thispagestyle{firststyle}

\maketitle\thispagestyle{fancy}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Section two}

Sample document

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called `\thispagestyle` twice on the same page, the second time again with the default style. Since `\thispagestyle` will only affect the style on the current page, you don't need to reset the style like this.

However, you should call `\thispagestyle` after `\maketitle`, because `\maketitle` internally calls `\thispagestyle{plain}`.

```
% vim:ft=tex:
%
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

% Use if Arial font unavailable
% \usepackage{helvet}
% \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

% Geometry has to be loaded before the footer
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 bottom=20mm,
 top=20mm
}

\usepackage{lastpage} % for the last page number
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
% Add a line above footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} % default is 0pt
% Add a line below header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyfoot[OR]{\footnotesize \thepage\ /\ \pageref{LastPage}}

% Define style to be used for the first page
\fancypagestyle{firststyle}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt} 
  \fancyfoot[OR]{\footnotesize \thepage\ /\ \pageref{LastPage}}
}

% Title page configuration
\title{\vspace{-2cm}Title of the Document\vspace{-5mm}}
\author{Author\vspace{-5mm}}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

% Use special first page style on the first page

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firststyle}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Section two}

Sample document

\newpage

More text

\end{document}
```